# Is there a country where people votes don't equal one another based on their personal circumstances?

Tags: election, international, voting-systems

Sorry if this question is a bit harsh, but I am looking for any country (past or current) who implemented a system where people don't just have 1 equal vote each, a vote/point system that is based on their personal circumstances apart from wealth.

Example, a vote of an 18 years old who is going to live his next 60 years in the country doesn't equal one's vote who is 78 years old and might just die the next day.
Or a person who spent 7 years after school getting degrees doesn't equal one who went on claiming state support for 7 years after school.

Any sort of criteria(apart from wealth), doesn't have to be the ones above, just want to see if one exists, how is that country doing in general, would such system benefit it.

Comment: Related: [*Are/were there any countries where rich people have more votes?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/8623)

Comment: @JJJ, yes similar, but my question is whether a system looks into all aspects of one's life to determine how many votes/points they can vote.

Comment: Would a system like the Electoral College in the US count? Voters in different states cast ballots for electors who elect the president but those votes aren't equal (you could get a different outcome if you swap voters to tip the balance in one state but not another). Thinking about it, this reasoning might hold for any district-based system that uses winner take all.

Comment: @JJJ No, I am looking at a system that distinguishes between basic population votes on person's circumstances. To be honest, I am specifically interested in the two examples above, as I personally feel they are important factors (age and education) in deciding a nation's destiny

Comment: Okay, in that case I think you should clarify that they must be personal criteria, not something like place of residence (which determines where your vote counts in district systems) which simply changes when you move. Also, must they be current examples or do historical examples count as well?

Comment: Historical examples are good too, I just would like to see how a country with such voting system do/did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a [deleted answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/714/26455) by Gerrit.

[Universal multiple voting rights](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algemeen_meervoudig_stemrecht) (Original in Dutch - Google translation)

> The universal plural suffrage was introduced in Belgium in 1893 by Auguste Beernaert after a general strike and at the request of the Belgian Workers' Party with the support of social-progressive liberals.
>
> The constitutional reform of 1893-1894 increased the number of voters from 136,755 to 1,370,678. From now on, every male citizen from the age of 25 had the right to vote. Multiple voting rights implied that certain categories received two or more votes. Heads of households who were married and owned a home, owners of real estate, holders of savings accounts and holders of a higher education diploma received one or two additional votes.
>
> ...
>
> Universal multiple suffrage was abolished under pressure from the Belgian Workers' Party in 1919 , in favor of universal single suffrage for men who were at least 21 years of age.

Answer (score 3):

Southern Rhodesia, in 1961, set up two electoral rolls, Roll A for "Educated" (which equated to Whites, some people with mixed heritage, and some Asians) and Roll B for Black Africans, and those with less education.

The result was war, revolution and the Mugabe presidency.

Comment: Thanks. Even though this might have been called/meant to be based on education, it seems more of based on race, as I find it difficult to believe that there were no educated blacks who would be eligible to vote in the Educated roll.